# Configure wildcard domain on Cloudbees

Tags: cloud-hosting

I am trying to add a wildcard domain alias for a CloudBees RUN@Cloud application.
However I get the following error message:

> invalid hostname: *.domain.com

Comment: Do CloudBees support wildcard domains?  I couldn't find anything about it in their help system but I don't really have the right incentive to dig through it for very long.  You might be better off asking their support team.

Comment: I didn't see any information about it either, so I wanted to know if anyone had done it somehow. I opened a ticket to their support also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from the CloudBees support:

> We can set this up for paid apps. Please let us know the app ID and
>   wildcard that you want on your app.
>
> Spike Washburn CloudBees, Inc